# CSRF and ajax form submit in codeigniter 3 using knockout js click binding - Forbidden error

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, knockout.js

I am trying to submit a user form via ajax post method on click of a button through knockout js click binding. Error i am receiving is 403 - Forbidden.

I am sure that it has something to do with CSRF but unable to figure it out.

View.php:

```
<?php echo form_open('client/search_client_database', ['role' => 'form']); ?>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="search_client_input">Search for existing   clients</label>
      <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="search_client_input" name="search_client_input" placeholder="Search for existing clients...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-bind="click: search_client">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

On click of button, knockout Js click binding is trigged to initiate a ajax call to controller. Knockout js code is in a separate js file which is loaded along with the view.

Client.js File:

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
var url = base_url+"/client/";

this.search_client = function()
        {           
            crsf = $("input[name=csrf_test_name]").val();
            dataString = $("#search_client_input").val();
            alert(crsf);
            $.ajax({
                url: url+"search_client_database",
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                data: {crsf: crsf, data: dataString},
                success: function(customer_details) {
                    alert(customer_details);                    
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller:

```
public function search_client_database()
    {
        $data = $this->input->post('data');
        echo $data;
    }
```

I keep getting xhr error 403 i.e. Forbidden. There is nothing wrong in the URL.

Comment: You have to send back the csrf token with the same name what is configured in `$config['csrf_token_name']`. So try with `data: {"csrf_test_name": crsf, data: dataString},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send back the csrf token with the same name what is configured in `$config['csrf_token_name']`.

In your case based on your code it is called `csrf_test_name`, so you need to use that in the `data` in your Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url + "search_client_database",
  type: "post",
  cache: false,
  data: {
    "csrf_token_name": crsf,
    data: dataString
  },
  success: function(customer_details) {
    alert(customer_details);
  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```